# Add class to element

Tags: jquery, class, addition

Like this, I have two tabs, so when i click on one it's active, logic. Now im trying to make difference between active and inactive tab, but not with .css property, but I wanna' add specific class to clicked tab, like this:

```
$(".tab1").addClass('active');
```

but, no good. Also have in mind that I'm using external css file.

```
<div id="menuitem" class="tab1"></div>
<div id="menuitem" class="tab2"></div>

.active {
    width: 170px;
    height: 70px;
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}

#menuitem {
    width: 170px;
    height: 70px;
    float: right;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: You should make your ID's unique, not your classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't use same `id` on different elements, `id`'s must be unique and try this:

**jQuery:**

```
$('.menuitem').click(function() {
    $('.menuitem').removeClass('active');
    //removes active class from all menu items

    $(this).addClass('active');
    //adds active class to clicked one
});
```

**html:**

```
<div id="tab1" class="menuitem"></div>
<div id="tab2" class="menuitem"></div>
```

**css:** you don't need to define same properties to active class, just define the difference:

```
.active { background-color: red; }

.menuitem {
  width: 170px;
  height: 70px;
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not have same id for two divs in HTML. Try changing your HTML like this.

```
<div id="menuitem1" class="menuitem tab1"></div>
<div id="menuitem2" class="menuitem tab2"></div>

.active {
background-color: red;
}

.menuitem {
width: 170px;
height: 70px;
float: right;
background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Just another note, you don't need to repeat the identical properties in the .active class. Since the only difference is background-color, you can exclude width, height, and float.

Answer (score 2):

The other issue might be that you're running your jQuery function before the div element exists.

So either, move the code

```
$(".tab1").addClass('active');
```

below the div's you want to change, or wrap it in a document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tab1").addClass('active');
});
```

which will wait till the dom has been created before running your code.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `id`s should always be unique.

The cause of your issue however, is css specificity.  An `id` rule is more specific than a class one.  Try this instead.

```
#menuitem.active {
width: 170px;
height: 70px;
float: right;
background-color: red;
}

#menuitem {
width: 170px;
height: 70px;
float: right;
background-color: white;
}
```

Keep in mind though that this will work to overcome the specificity issue.  It does not address the fact that you need to get rid of your duplicated `id`s.

[CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)